# Grease Pencil 2.8 Continuous Stroke

Tags: grease-pencil

In Blender 2.8 (Grease pencil),  is it possible to quickly resume drawing an interrupted line **(on a surface)** by connecting the beginning of the new stroke to the end of the previous one without going into edit mode to join the vertices?

Answer (score 3):

To resume a drawn line you can select Stroke under the Stroke Placement option in the Blender 2.8 viewport, and choose All points, First point or Endpoints for attachment.

Comment: But how can I draw on a mesh surface using this method?

Comment: Ah. It doesn't exist currently as a direct option because they are two separate placement modes. It makes sense to have it as an individual option. Outside of merging vertices there may be other options but it depends on what the end result goal is for the lines. One option instead of finding the vertices is to simply select the edges and join those instead.